# Close DLL file handle opened by LoadLibrary

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

How can I close the file handle opened by a `LoadLibrary` call on a .dll while keeping the library loaded? `FreeLibrary` will not work for example.

In my case there is a program I want to keep open that has the DLL open, but I don't want to close the program each time I recompile and replace the DLL. I don't care if the program has an old version of the library in memory. The DLL is also used by another program which is why I want to be able to replace it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible because a "loaded" DLL is a memory mapped file. This means that "closing the handle" would remove it from memory because it's not *copied* to memory, only *mapped*.

This is why DLLs are so memory efficient as long as all programs use the exact same file - it (almost) doesn't cost any extra memory to load it hundreds of times! (In case you wonder: it's mapped as copy-on-write so modifying it in memory won't modify the file on disk but instead copy the one affected 4k page to actual memory and modify it there.)

You can however rename the file (or move it, as long as it's on the same volume, which is technically also a renaming operation) while it's still in use. Then you can create a new file with the original name and later delete the old file after it was unloaded everywhere.

You can also mark the old file as to be deleted automatically on the next reboot using `MoveFileEx(MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT)` but this requires elevated privileges. A popular choice by non-elevated updaters/uninstallers to avoid that is to drop a batch or vbs file in the local appdata folder that deletes the file and then itself (which *does* work because scripts *are* copied to memory) and register it in the per-user `RunOnce` registry key.

(Note that opening the file with `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` won't work.)

Comment: Interesting, I did not know of memory mapped files before this. Thanks.

Comment: [FreeLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibrary) decrements the reference count on the library. It doesn't necessarily unload the module from the calling process' address space. This distinction is quite significant.

Comment: There is no file handle to close. There isn't even a section (file mapping) handle to close. An `HMODULE` is the base address of the loaded module. In a kernel debugger you can use `!vad <address> 1` to show information that includes the control area, which references the file object. In this case the file object only has kernel pointer references, no handle references. It's opened with `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE` sharing, which is why it can be renamed, which requires opening the file with `DELETE` access.

Comment: Opening an image-mapped DLL with delete-on-close fails the `NtCreateFile` system call with `STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE` (not `STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION`) because the file is mapped as an image. For an example of code that checks for an active (non-flushable) image section, see [`FatOpenExistingFcb`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/create.c#L3572) in the fastfat sample driver, which calls [`MmFlushImageSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-mmflushimagesection).